# add conditionals to a displayed external xml feed

Tags: php, xml

I found the following code online and customized it to pull the xml feeds from our online calendar software and display event information on several different WP pages.

```
function otpl_add_class_feed() {
    if ( is_page(48) ) {
        $url = "http://orion.lib.mi.us/evanced/lib/eventsxml.asp?ag=&et=Computer+Class&nd=31&dm=exml&alltime=1";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        foreach($xml->item as$item)
            {
                echo "<div id='computer-classes'>";
                echo "<p class='event-title'><a href='".$item->link."'>".$item->title."</a></p>";
                echo "<p class='event-date'>".$item->date." from ".$item->time." to ".$item->endtime."</p>";
                echo "<p class='event-desc'>".$item->description."</p>";
                echo "<p class='event-signup'><a href='".$item->link."'>Register Online</a>.</p>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
    } // END IF
}
```

How can I include a conditional statement so that if $item->date. is populated the above code will run but if $item->date. is empty then another code stating that there are no events scheduled will run?  I'm sure it's something simple but my understanding of syntax isn't very strong.  My few attempts have broken my functions page.

Comment: This is really a PHP question. Though I would advise you to look into [WP transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) so that you are not constantly reloading the XML.

Comment: You can try `if( isset($item->date) && strlen($item->date)>0 ){...}`

Comment: @vancoder  Thanks for the tip about WP transients.  I'm guessing you have some experience using that feature.  Is there an expiration period you recommend as a sweet spot for saved reloading versus timely updates for changed information?

Comment: There's no all-purpose sweet spot. It would entirely depend on how often your feed is likely to be updated, and how much traffic you are getting. Probably anything from a minute or 2 to several hours, usually.

Comment: Thanks @vancoder. I'll check with my network admin and she what she thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @birgie pointed out, add a conditional statement to check that the date has been set:

> `if ( isset( $item->date ) && strlen( $item->date ) > 0 ) { ... }`